# Statistical Significance on shops performances with a marketing promotion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, ab-test, method-comparison

I have data regarding the performances of shops on a certain time period: in this data some shops had an active marketing promotion, and some didn't. I would like to understand whether the shops with the promotion improved their performances more than the other group.

I have formulated the problem in the following terms: how many shops improved their performances (wrt the previous time period) among the two groups?
In this case, my results are

| Group | Total # Shops | # Shops with improved performances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No Promo | 37907 | 23762 |
| With Promo | 1007 | 801 |

Running a significance test, data suggests that the difference is significant (p-value < 0.05), so I would have concluded that shops with active promo are more likely to improve their performances.

I would like now to estimate how much the improvement is, so if there's a difference in the mean growth between the two groups. In this case, data are:

| Group | Total # Shops | Mean Growth | Std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No Promo | 37907 | 0.45 | 0.8896 |
| With Promo | 1007 | 0.83 | 1.0367 |

At this point, do I have to run a test on the difference in growth mean to understand if they are significant? If so, which kind of test should be used?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're in need of the chi-square test, which tests for variable independency. If the test is significant (let's consider *p* < .05), your variables are related to each other.

I've created your example in R using the following code:

```
# creating promo
promo <- c(rep('no', 37907), rep(c('yes'), 1007)) # creating promo

# creating improvement
improved <- c(rep('yes', 23762), rep('no', 14145), rep('yes', 801), rep('no', 206)) # creating improvement

# creating dataframe object
df <- data.frame(promo = promo, improved = improved)
```

I then read `library(gmodels)` and tested for independece using the function `CrossTable()`

```
x <- CrossTable(df$promo, df$improved, chisq = T, fisher = T)
```

The resulting table is the following:

```
Total Observations in Table:  38914 

 
             | df$improved 
df$promo |        no |       yes | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
          no |     14145 |     23762 |     37907 | 
             |     1.956 |     1.143 |           | 
             |     0.373 |     0.627 |     0.974 | 
             |     0.986 |     0.967 |           | 
             |     0.363 |     0.611 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
         yes |       206 |       801 |      1007 | 
             |    73.638 |    43.023 |           | 
             |     0.205 |     0.795 |     0.026 | 
             |     0.014 |     0.033 |           | 
             |     0.005 |     0.021 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |     14351 |     24563 |     38914 | 
             |     0.369 |     0.631 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

The actual statistical results are:

```
Statistics for All Table Factors


Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  119.7606     d.f. =  1     p =  7.137585e-28 

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  119.0375     d.f. =  1     p =  1.027699e-27 

 
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
------------------------------------------------------------
Sample estimate odds ratio:  2.314598
```

Note that *p* < .05, it's even below .001. That being said, *p* is not an effect size measure, and that's what you're trying to know, as I understand.

Note the `Sample estimate odds ratio:  2.314598` in the final line of the output. That's your effect size. What that number means is that the variable *promo* increases the odds of *improved performances* of a store by 2.31 times.